# Extracting data from an Excel sheet based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook tracking parts being produced including vendors, quantities and delivery dates etc. It is a big file, and I regularly have to manually pull specific parts out to create reports.

What I'm trying to do with VBA:
-Test each row of a specific sheet for an overdue shipment based on specified delivery date
-If the part is overdue, copy the entire row into a new workbook
-Continue the process row by row until it reaches the end
-Pull out every part with all its details that is overdue into a new sheet

What I got so far, for a test workbook:

```vb
Sub btnPrintReport_click()

    Dim part As String, vendor As String, date_due As String

    part = Range("L3:L10").Select
    vendor = Range("M3:M10").Select
    date_due = Range("N3:N10").Select

    If date_due < Date Then
        Range("A21").Value = part
        Range("B21").Value = vendor
        Range("C21").Value = date_due
    End If

End Sub
```

The best I could get is to read my test book and print the first values from L, M, N but then it stops because I cannot get it to continue the process for all other rows (it reads row 3, and stops).

I figured a loop would fix that but I'm struggling to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, you can see how new i am to this...

Answer (score 0):

you need for loop to read data in your worksheet then check data.

1. this is the way to find last row content data

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row  ' ,12 mean col L
```

2. Then make a for loop to run, some thing like that

```
for i = 3 to lastRow
    'put your check and copy process here
    ' for example
    part = cells(i,12)  ' i = 3 then its mean cells(3,12) = L3 then so on
    .
    .
    .

    If date_due < Date Then

        cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row,1).value  = part

        cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row,2).value = vendor

        cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row,3).value = date_due

        End If
next i
```

Comment: Thank you, i will use this logic to re-structure my current code. I will update this post with what i come up with!